# Is there a command line program or library that turns image files into ASCII art?

Tags: ruby, image, image-processing

Is there such a thing? I would like to use it in a Ruby program.

Comment: I have Googled for it, and the search results are too noisy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this
http://csl.sublevel3.org/jp2a/

Also, there may be some stuff with Imagemagick

Answer (score 4):

There's [`jp2a`](http://csl.sublevel3.org/jp2a/) which converts jpegs. It's pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another solution. There is also AAlib. http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/

You should be able to read in the output or pipe into a file for reading.